# getView called when scrolling.

Tags: android

In my Custom adapter for my `listview`, I've added an animation like this:

```
        View lastAddedItem = parent.getChildAt(0);  
        if(lastAddedItem != null)  {
            Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.push);
            lastAddedItem.startAnimation(a);
        }
```

This code applies animation to the 0'th item in the list. This animation is applied when I scroll the list as well, of course the list has to be rendered once again, when scrolled, but is there someway I can prevent this? Remember, keep in mind that this code is in the method `getView()`

Thanks alot!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just check if `position == 0`?

Comment: hm, am not quite sure that you mean by that? I have to grab a specific `View` in order to apply an animation. Would be great if you could post an example.

Comment: I didn't test it and may sound naive, but why you just don't put a boolean before the animation and let it pass just one time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run the animation on the 0th item, you should just be able to check the `position` variable that comes with `getView()`. If it's 0, run the animation on the supplied `View`.

**Edit:** Added a boolean flag per comments.

```
boolean isFirstRun = true;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        // init view
        ...
    } 
    // populate view
    ...

    if(position == 0 && isFirstRun) {
        isFirstRun = false;
        // do animation stuff to convertView
        // this will be the 0th item
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The animation looks a bit better, but the 1st item in the list will have an anmation when I scrool from bottom to top. And when the listview isn't scrollable the items will animate randomly.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted it run any time the view was visible. You can fix that with a boolean in addition. One second to update the code.

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other a bit. I try to animate the `View` only when an item is added. Not when I scroll the list. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Oh. Yes, we definitely misunderstood each other. I'll leave this here for now, so others don't make the same mistake. You might want to consider editing your question to make it clearer, though.